# Spring get all @Entity classes

Tags: spring, entity

Is there a way to get all @Entity classes in Spring?
I can't seem to find any solution.
Thanks.

answer:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
   <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
   <version>0.9.5</version>
</dependency>
```

will do this easily ;)

Answer (score 26):

Why do you need this? I suppose you are in a JPA context, then you can do it like this:

```
entityManager.getMetamodel().getEntities();
```

Comment: Above line of return type ?

Comment: Thanks! Our use-case was validating custom annotation that we added on entities.

Comment: This should be the excepted answer as it does not required any additional libraries to solve the problem.